# How to retrieve the particular X th position of node using xpath?

Tags: xml, linq, xpath

This is my Xml Document.

```
<w:document>
<w:body>
   <w:p>para1</w:p>
   <w:p>para2</w:p>
   <w:p>para3</w:p>
   <w:p>para4</w:p>
   <w:p>para5</w:p>
   <w:p>para6</w:p>
   <w:p>para7</w:p> 
   <w:p>para8</w:p>
   <w:p>para9</w:p>
   <w:p>para10</w:p>
</w:body>
</w:document>
```

Now, i want to retrieve the text of 7th .ie,Para7.

How do i get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can index into an XPath expression using `[]` brackets. For example, you might use `//w:p[7]` to access the 7th element.

Note that XPath indexing is 1-based indexing not 0-based indexing.

Comment: Wrong answer! In fact, depending on the XML document,  `//someName[7]` may select any number of elements, or even nothing -- even when the total number of `someName` elements is much more than 7. -1.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, The purpose of the answer was to demonstrate the indexing syntax for XPath. Also, since it depends on the XML and the user's specific requirements, I would hardly call it the wrong answer.

Comment: @_Shane S. Anderson: Not only is this a wrong answer -- it is harmful as it influences people to believe `//someName[k]` is the right way to select the k-th `someName` element in the document. We shouldn't allow disinformation like this. **Please, consider correcting asap or deleting this "answer"**.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/*[7]/text()
```

If you have registered the namespaces correctly with your XPath engine's API, you can use:

```
/w:document/w:body/w:p[7]/text()
```

**Note**:

Be aware that there are problems using the `[]` operator together with the `//` pseudo-operator: in this specific simple case the expression

```
//w:p[7]
```

selects the wanted element, however in general it selects *every `w:p` element that is the 7th (in document order) `w:p` child of its parent*.

**So, when evaluated against this document**:

```
<w:document xmlns:w="w:w">
    <w:body>
     <a>
        <w:p>para1</w:p>
        <w:p>para2</w:p>
        <w:p>para3</w:p>
   </a> 
   <b>
        <w:p>para4</w:p>
        <w:p>para5</w:p>
        <w:p>para6</w:p>
        <w:p>para7</w:p>
        <w:p>para8</w:p>
        <w:p>para9</w:p>
        </b>
        <w:p>para10</w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

**the expression `//w:p[7]` selects nothing**.

**However, when evaluated against this document**:

```
<w:document xmlns:w="w:w">
    <w:body>
     <a>
        <w:p>para1</w:p>
        <w:p>para2</w:p>
        <w:p>para3</w:p>
        <w:p>para4</w:p>
        <w:p>para5</w:p>
        <w:p>para6</w:p>
        <w:p>para7</w:p>
        <w:p>para8</w:p>
   </a>
   <b>
        <w:p>para9</w:p>
        <w:p>para10</w:p>
        <w:p>para11</w:p>
        <w:p>para12</w:p>
        <w:p>para13</w:p>
        <w:p>para14</w:p>
        <w:p>para15</w:p>
    </b>
 </w:body>
</w:document>
```

**the same expression selects**:

```
<w:p xmlns:w="w:w">para7</w:p>
<w:p xmlns:w="w:w">para15</w:p>
```